# How to step over method call in Eclipse Debugger?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, shortcut

In Eclipse debugger, the default step options are:

- <kbd>F5</kbd>: Step into method
- <kbd>F6</kbd>: Step over line
- <kbd>F7</kbd>: Step out of method

Often I do have code like this:

```
obj.getMember().doStuff();
```

Or maybe even worse (please don't question the code design, just making this up):

```
obj.getInstance().createSomething().getMember().doStuff();
```

Usually I want to inspect `doStuff()` only, but <kbd>F6</kbd> will not step over individual method calls, but it will step over the entire line. So I end up hitting <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>F7</kbd> until I reach `doStuff()`.

My question is: Is there any option to step over method calls (= do <kbd>F5</kbd> and <kbd>F7</kbd> in one shortcut)? Would be cool, if I had to tap X, X, X, <kbd>F5</kbd> only to reach `doStuff()`.

**// Edit for clarification:** I'm looking for a keyboard-only solution. I know there are several ways I can reach my method (e.g. breakpoints), but I'm asking for a combined shortcut for <kbd>F5</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>, so to say.

Answer (score 4):

You have to select the method you want to step into and then with the right click of the mouse you will find the option **Step into Selection** :

[image: Step into selection]

> Select the Step Into Selection command to step into the currently
> selected statement in the active editor.

*You must have program execution suspended for this command to be available.*

As you can see from the image above you can just press OPTION and F5 on a mac once selected the method to step into ...

Shortcut :<kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>

Comment: Thank you, but I'm rather looking for a shortcut to skip over method calls with no mouse selections being involved.

Comment: As the answer explains, the keyboard shortcut allows using Step into Selection without using the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You could also place a breakpoint into `doStuff()` and, when you reach `obj.getInstance().createSomething().getMember().doStuff();` just resume execution (keybinding: <kbd>F8</kbd>:

[image]

All the intermediate frames will be executed and the debugger will pause directly in `doStuff()` again. This of course means that you cannot decide from run to run like you can do with aleroot's `Step into Selection` suggestion.

Comment: Thank you. I'm aware of breakpoints and the resume feature, but I'm rather looking for a combined shortcut. I'll edit my question for clarification.

Comment: Well, `Resume` has `F8` as its default key binding, so if you can live with the break point per se, you can do this with one key press. Some kind of selection, either before hand via break point, or in situ via mouse will probably have to happen. At least there is no feature like "always pause in the last call of any one expression".

Comment: I added another, totally orthogonal answer to your question since I now understand the core of your question, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, something completely different, since I think I understand the core of your question a bit better now.

There's no predefined skip-over-this-method command afaik, so you can [build one yourself](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCommandsAdvanced/article.html). This touches some advanced topics so I'll only post some pointers here:

1. Create an Eclipse plugin.
2. In that plugin, declare a command with a keybinding like <kbd>Alt+F8</kbd> and implement the command's default handler
3. In the handler of your command, invoke the built-in commands which are bound to the `Step into` and `Step out` actions. You can find their IDs by looking into the Eclipse source or trying the [Plugin-Spy](https://scratsh.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/eclipse-3-5-plug-in-spy-and-menus/) feature.
4. Package up your plugin and start your Eclipse with it included.

This way you'll reuse the predefined functionality and automate your <kbd>F5</kbd> plus <kbd>F7</kbd> mashing into a single command with relatively small effort.